# Implementing partial word search in Apache Solr

Tags: solr

I'm new to `Apache Solr` (v. 5.2.1), but I've already managed to do something - like indexing all files in a directory and doing simple search. Now, what I want - is to implement partial word search. In this [blog](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/apache-solr-configuring-partial-word-search-functionality/2012-12-12) the advice is to edit `schema.xml`, but I'm not sure exactly what schema file to edit, since there are dozens of them in `solar` directory. Or probably you know another way of implementing partial word search.

Comment: By partial word search, do you mean something like, "if a user searches for 'jura', then one of the returned searches should be 'jurassic park'"?

Comment: As you have already setup Solr, you must have defined a core - look in its conf directory for the relevant `schema.xml`. And BTW, the link you provided deals with Solr 3.6, so keep in mind that any information given might be outdated.

Comment: @ TMBT Exactly! BTW, I know about wildcards, however, I tried searching with a search word like *assic. But it does not work. I will not find jurassic park.

Comment: @ f_puras I can't find `conf` directory inside the root directory of `Solr 5.2.1`

Comment: There is a conf directory, but it is very deep inside the root directory: `./solr-5.2.1/server/solr/configsets/basic_configs/conf`. And inside this `conf` directory there is a schema file. So, do people mean this folder and this file, when they talk about editing schema file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection schema.xml file is located in the collection config directory. In  Solr Admin UI - Core Admin, click on the collection check InstanceDir.

Inside that directory, there should be another directory called conf, schema is in there.

As for wildcard search, Solr already comes with some wildard searches, however to fully search for any part of the word I would suggest configuring ngram tokenizer. Here is a bit more info on it:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-N-GramTokenizer

Comment: So, I see four folders named like `gettingstarted_shard{N}_replica{K}`. But inside these folders there are only `core.properties` file and `./data` folder. There is no conf directory.

Comment: I see, when creating a collection using the solr command, include a -d argument and pass it "basic_configs" like -d basic_configs

Comment: Can you, please, give the full command that creates a collection and its schema file?

Comment: try this, replace 7071 with your solr port, make sure you are in the bin directory.    $./solr create_collection -p 7071 -c test -d basic_configs

Comment: Unfortunately, with `-p 7071` I get an error `request to http://localhost:7071/solr/admin/info/system failed due to ...`. So I tried simply  `$./solr create_collection -c test -d basic_configs`. I see that there is now a new directory `test_shard1_replica1`. However, there is no conf directory or schema.xml file inside it.

Comment: `replace 7071 with your solr port`. I guess, you mean by this, that I should have restarted solr on a new port. So, I did it. However, when I now go to 127.0.0.1:7071/solr/#/~cores I see a promt window, that asks me to add a core, however, when I press `ok` I get a new error message that `Error creating SolrCore 'test' ...`

Comment: So, it seems as if there is still to much to take care of. Simply restarting solr and creating a new collection with `-d basic_configs` bring a new bunch of issues and errors.

Comment: You don't need to move solr to that port, you just need to specify the current port your Solr is running on.

Comment: Well, I replaced 7071 with a port that solr is running on, but at this time when I try to do `$./solr create_collection -c test -d basic_configs` command, I get one brand new error message `ERROR: Solr at http://... is running in standalone mode, please use the create_core command ...`. I wonder what is the next error message down the road.

Comment: Ok... so replace create_collection with create_core